# What's a more sophisticated word for "gadget"?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, synonyms

I'm looking for a word that isn't tacky like *gadget*, but that describes interesting and novel technological items.

Comment: _thingamajig, doohickey, frammis, whatchamcallit, whojigger, whatsis_, etc.

Comment: @John, sure, but for sophisticated, go with *[gizmo](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=gizmo)*, one of the many synonyms of *[thingy](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wikisaurus:thingy)*.

Comment: I'd tempted to suggest _widget_, but, without knowing **why** you think gadget is "tacky", it's hard to suggest alternate words. As it stands now, there's no way to know whether or not _widget_ is even tackier than _gadget_.

Comment: Yes, _interesting and novel technological items_ and _tacky_ don't belong in the same referential universe. People who can perceive one normally can't perceive the other.

Answer (score 6):

***"Device"*** or ***"Apparatus"***

> Definition of ***"Device"***:
>
> 1. A thing made or adapted for a particular task, esp. a mechanism or electronic instrument.
>
> Synonyms: appliance - gadget - contrivance - apparatus - gear
>
> ---
>
> Definition of ***"Apparatus"***:
>
> 1. The equipment needed for a particular activity or purpose.

Definitions from dictionary.com

Answer (score 2):

The term *[widget](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/widget#Noun)* is widely used and well-accepted in its software sense (“a reusable element of a graphical user interface”, per [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUI_widget)), but it also has a sense “A placeholder name for an unnamed, unspecified, or hypothetical manufactured good or product” that may apply in the current context.  *Widget* is only slightly more “sophisticated” than *gadget*, if at all, but the weight of acceptance of *widget* in the software context lends it some cachet.

However, an “interesting and novel technological item” is perhaps slightly more likely to be referred to as a *[marvel](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/marvel#Noun)*.

Answer (score 1):

An often misused, but perhaps suitable word, is *utility*. It is used often in a technological context, but more often about little useful GUI-driven pieces of software rather than devices. I've still heard it in conversation about devices, at least. It certainly sounds less sort of...child-like... than *gadget*.