# Looking for a "thing" word

Tags: single-word-requests

Looking for an all purpose word that can replace "thing" referring to a device or artifact.

"I had a USB stick, a cable and other things in my bag."

Comment: What's wrong with "thing"? Anyway, a thesaurus should be able to answer this question.

Comment: 'Other things' often sounds bare or even a naive usage. "Amongst other things, I had a USB stick and a cable in my bag."

Comment: You want a countable noun for the mass noun _stuff_ (or _shit,_ if it isn't your stuff). I don't know of one; we have phrases like _some stuff, a lotta stuff, too much stuff_ ("), or _a few things_, but nothing much inbetween.

Comment: [Gadget](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/103728/191178) (as suggested by thesauruses as a synonym of *device*)?

Comment: 'Paraphernalia', 'bits and bobs', 'items', depending on how causal you need the tone to be.

Comment: I am voting to close the question for these reasons: **You need to explain why "things" does not work for you**. And also tell us what research you did and which words you discarded and why. For example, I would automatically dismiss "artifacts" because I usually associate that word with museum pieces, handmade objects hundreds of years old, pieces of great historical interest etc.

Comment: Thanks for closing the question for me. I was satisfied with the range of word ideas offered by the community but am unfamiliar with the etiquette of this forum. I will close future questions that I feel have met my needs.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a word with a broad meaning, then "items" could work. If you want something focused more on technology, then the mass nouns "gear" or "equipment" could work. If you put any of those terms into a thesaurus, then you'll get other options, of course.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of words but my favorite word for this scenario is **hardware** (or more specifically **computer hardware**). Click the [link](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/hardware) and check for the **1st** and **3rd** definitions.

> "I had a USB stick, a cable and other ***hardware*** in my bag."

Note: The word hardware is uncountable noun and hence, plural of hardware is also hardware.

Other words can be- components, stuffs, items, or computer peripheral depending on the context.